# How to add a regression line with linear and quadratic components in ggplot?

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, scatter-plot, glm

So this is kinda a complicated question and I have no idea what my problem is. I have to create a scatterplot using ggplot and "add a line of best fit to the scatterplot that has both a linear and a quadratic component." Doing that seems impossible to me and when I asked my professor he just told me to look in our notes. My best guess is to fit a glm regression line. So I used the exact code from our notes for adding a glm regresion line: `+ geom_smooth(method="glm", method.args=list(family=Gamma(link="log")))`

When I run the ggplot with the line there is no error but the line is not shown on the graph.

```
ggplot(data=glm_dataframe, mapping=aes(x=log_time, y=slope_mass_vector)) + 
geom_point() + 
xlab("Log Time Interval") + 
ylab("Mass Slope") + 
ggtitle("Mass")+ 
geom_smooth(method="glm", 
 method.args=list(family=Gamma(link="log")))
```

FYI, prior to this we created a `for` loop to run multiple GLMs and return the values in a data frame. After doing a lot of research I was thinking maybe the problem was that the values weren't numeric because that was a problem other people had. So I transformed all of the values inside the `for` loop to numeric but it didn't fix my problem. Here is the code for the data frame and `for` loop in case it is the cause of the problem:

```
#create empty vectors for the for loop outputs
    time_interval_vector <- character()
    intercept_vector <- character()
    slope_mass_vector <- character()
    slope_NDVI_vector <- character()
    slope_HFI_vector <- character()
    p_value_intercept_vector <- character()
    p_value_NDVI_vector <- character()
    p_value_HFI_vector <- character()
    p_value_mass_vector <- character()
    R2_vector <- character()

    #create a for loop
    for(i in unique(displace$Time_Interval))
      {
      #create a glm
      displace_glm <- glm(Displacement~NDVI + HFI + Mass, data=displace[displace$Time_Interval==i,], family=Gamma(link="log"))

      #pull out the desired values from the summary
      intercept <- as.numeric(as.character(coef(summary(displace_glm))))[1]
      slope_NDVI <- as.numeric(as.character(coef(summary(displace_glm))))[2]
      slope_HFI <- as.numeric(as.character(coef(summary(displace_glm))))[3]
      slope_mass <- as.numeric(as.character(coef(summary(displace_glm))))[4]
      p_value_intercept <- as.numeric(as.character(coef(summary(displace_glm))))[13]
      p_value_NDVI <- as.numeric(as.character(coef(summary(displace_glm))))[14]
      p_value_HFI <- as.numeric(as.character(coef(summary(displace_glm))))[15]
      p_value_mass <- as.numeric(as.character(coef(summary(displace_glm))))[16]
      R2 <- NagelkerkeR2(displace_glm)[[2]]

      #add the values to the empty vectors
      time_interval_vector <- c(time_interval_vector, i)
      intercept_vector <- c(intercept_vector, intercept)
      slope_mass_vector <- c(slope_mass_vector, slope_mass)
      slope_NDVI_vector <- c(slope_NDVI_vector, slope_NDVI)
      slope_HFI_vector <- c(slope_HFI_vector, slope_HFI)
      R2_vector <- c(R2_vector, R2)
      p_value_intercept_vector <- c(p_value_intercept_vector, p_value_intercept)
      p_value_NDVI_vector <- c(p_value_NDVI_vector, p_value_NDVI)
      p_value_HFI_vector <- c(p_value_HFI_vector, p_value_HFI)
      p_value_mass_vector <- c(p_value_mass_vector, p_value_mass)
      }
    #combine the vectors into a data frame    
    glm_dataframe <- data.frame(time_interval_vector, intercept_vector, slope_mass_vector, slope_NDVI_vector, slope_HFI_vector, R2_vector, p_value_intercept_vector,p_value_NDVI_vector, p_value_HFI_vector, p_value_mass_vector)
```

Comment: Do not edit the question to [invalidate existing answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290704/3956566).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I an see you are trying to fit a glm by means of gamma distribution with a log link.

```
stat_smooth(aes(y=<your y value>), method = "lm", formula = y ~ x + I(x^2))
```

Here an example with mtcars data

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=mpg))+
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(aes(y=mpg), method = "lm", formula = y ~ x + I(x^2))
```

[image]

Comment: Your x and y in the aes should be the x and y variable in your original data frame. Could you like to put the first 10 rows of your data including your x and y variables?